# PrimeNG filter using array object

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I wanted to know if it was possible to use an array of objects for filtering something into a table ?

I'm using Angular 6 and PrimeNG 7

My p-table looks like this:

```
<p-table #table class="ui-table ui-table-responsive" [value]="arrays"  [columns]="cols" >
    ...
    <div class="col-xl-4">        
    <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
    <input type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Rechercher" (input)="table.filter($event.target.value, cols['sort'], 'contains')" style="width:auto">
    </div>
    ...
<p-table>
```

I want to use **filter()** and not **globalFilter()** because i need to specify the field that i want to filter.

The content of cols is this:

```
this.cols = [
  { field: 'number', sort: 'number', header: 'The number' },
  { field: 'type', sort: 'type', header: 'The type' },
  { field: 'place', field2: 'placeName', sort: 'place.placeName', header: 'The place'},
  { field: 'city', field2: 'cityName',  sort: 'city.cityName', header: 'The city' },
  ...
  ...
];
```

For the moment my filter won't work..

Answer (score 1):

you are not passing the column for col.field pass your column

```
(input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)"
```